# Mark city on Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.s&amp;key=ABQIAAAA7DHqr4azRz3GFI1rF3F05RTzDhEz38nzyWFNvKs6H8gdGpqkAhQDDMdxJ-xDhaiiIJRibJNuURlZOw"            
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

function load() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
         var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
         map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());
         var MapTypes = map.getMapTypes();
         MapTypes[0].getName= function() { return "Mapa";}
         MapTypes[1].getName = function() { return "Satelitarna";}
         MapTypes[2].getName = function() { return "Hybrydowa";}
         map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
         map.setCenter(new GLatLng(52.7592485, 19.4559833), 6);
         var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(54.1943219, 16.1714908));
            map.addOverlay(marker);

}
}

//]]>
</script> 
  </head>
  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
  </body>
```

Variable "marker" is responsible for mark place on map. Now I must to enter coordinates.
I need mark city, but name of the city, no coordinates.

Comment: Looks like you're using V2 of the Maps API which has been deprecated.  You should be using V3 of the Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the geocoding API: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/.